# from ActivityB i want to send ID to FragmentA and to update list in FramgentA

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, fragment

From ActivityB I want to send an ID to FragmentA, in order to update a list in FramgentA. How can I achieve this?

[image]

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

You can use mvvm pattern, and one viewModel for activity, so it would be the same for both of fragments.
Inside viewModel you can store observable int field, so whenever it gets updated views got notified.

You can find more information about viewModel here : https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/lifecycle/ViewModel

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest looking into `startActivityForResult`.

`ActivityA` contains `FragmentA`. When you need to open `ActivityB`, call `startActivityForResult` instead of just `startActivity`.

In `FragmentA`

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, ActivityB.class)
startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE)
```

And then you can recieve it within the Fragment's `onActivityResult`.

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
   if( requestCode == REQUEST_CODE ) {
       // handle the result, you can get the id from the data.
   }
}
```

You must override `ActivityA`'s `onActivityResult` to ensure the `FragmentA` recieves it.

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
   super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

Comment: Hi 
Activity B I call from adapter not from Fragmemnt A

Comment: @Androiddev You can pass in an interface to handle the onClick for the adapter. And implement it within the Fragment, so the Fragment is aware that you want to open a new Activity. That will also move the Activity logic out of your adapter.